# Is it safe to use session in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I wonder if using codeigniter session is safe.
Some earlier versions said no because the default configuration file was configured in a way that was unsafe.

In the current version (3.1.2), have this problem? Do I need to worry about using encription_key, for example?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is very vague which is why you got downvoted and no one has responded. Yes, its safe. Codeigniter is very active with safety and security, and does regular updates to address security concerns. If you have actual specific questions would suggest you post them to https://forum.codeigniter.com But don't just post 'i heard that...' because this is the internet and you can hear whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are stored on the server. As long as the server is safe, sessions should be safe as well. CodeIgniter's session class is just a wrapper for PHP's native sessions.